# create template for one page

Tags: page-template, page-attributes

I want to create a one page template [here](http://schreinerei-lignum.de/contactWohnsinn) and this is the content of `page-contactWohnsinn.php`:
hello world

So the php file only contains hello world and is stored in `...wp-content/themes/mytheme`

I also created a page in the database with name `contactWohnsinn`
The page is visible on the link, but not the hello w.

Is it clear? Of course I did the mapping php-file-name and page-name.

Why is "hello world" not spread to the world?

Comment: Please elaborate what you need and what you have tried so far ? Paste code, if any !!

Comment: Have you assigned the page template of  `contactWohnsinn` with `page-contactWohnsinn.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your "page-contactWohnsinn.php" file,
And add this code to top of the file,

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Contact Wohnsinn
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
?>
```

and go to you page that you created in wp-admin,

choose the template "Contact Wohnsinn" from right side options...
and you are done..

Comment: I did not create a page in wp-admin, I did it like here http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/ But I did not use another style.css, neither a child theme, just copied the php in the theme dir. and added a page with the same name but without the "page" and the "-"

Comment: I got the solution, the error was that I used CamelCase in the file which Wp does not like at all.